# react native styling component

Tags: react-native, styling

I am trying to style a component but cant figure out how to do a couple of things. 
1) I want to apply a background color to 100% of my component

```
return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          style={styles.touchable}
          onPress={() =>
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Quotes', { name: this.props.name })}
        >
          <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
              <Image
                source={this.props.image}
                key={this.props.image}
                style={styles.imageStyle}
              />
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}> {this.props.name} </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  imageStyle: {
    height: 100,
    width: 100
  },
  touchable: {
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  },
  viewStyle: {
    height:100,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  },
  textStyle: {
    marginLeft: 20,
    width: 120,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 15
  }
}
```

I tried to apply the background color to touchable tag a view tag but none of this work.
Moreover Id like to position my image at the top left of the component using justifyContent: flex-start. But my elements inside the view tag keeps staying centered.

How can I achieve these goals[image] ?

The parent component is :

```
  render() {
    const {listStyle} = styles
    return (
      <ScrollView style={listStyle}>
        {this.renderCharacters(this.props.matches)}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }

}
const styles = {
  listStyle: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you render this `<TouchableWithoutFeedback />` component? Show its parent. Are you using anything like `alignItems: ' center' ` with `flexDirection: 'column'` for the parent.

Comment: hey @RaviRaj i edited with the parent component. no Im not using these properties on parent component